# Minus query in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sum, left-join

I was trying to do subtract between two of single `float` value from two tables:

The first one is:

```
select sum (cost) as "total cost" from (SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCT 
LEFT JOIN sell_bill ON sell_bill.PRODUCT_ID=PRODUCT.ID
WHERE (product.cost > sell_bill.PRICE)
```

It returns `240`.

The second one is :

```
select sum (price) as "total price" from (SELECT *
FROM PRODUCT 
LEFT JOIN sell_bill ON sell_bill.PRODUCT_ID=PRODUCT.ID
WHERE (product.cost > sell_bill.PRICE)
```

It returns `140`.

So this is what I tried:

```
select sum (cost) as "total cost" from (SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCT 
LEFT JOIN sell_bill ON sell_bill.PRODUCT_ID=PRODUCT.ID
WHERE (product.cost > sell_bill.PRICE)
minus 
select sum (price) as "total price" from (SELECT *
FROM PRODUCT 
LEFT JOIN sell_bill ON sell_bill.PRODUCT_ID=PRODUCT.ID
WHERE (product.cost > sell_bill.PRICE)
;
```

But it returned `240`... What's wrong ?

Comment: Sample data and desire results would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MINUS` operator does not do what you expect : it does not substract values, it operates on datasets (return all rows in the first SELECT statement that are not returned by the second SELECT statement).

Also, you don't need to use a subquery to compute the `SUM`, like : `SELECT SUM(cost) from (SELECT...`) ; I removed it.

I guess that you just want  :

```
SELECT 
    SUM(cost) - SUM(price)
FROM 
    product 
    LEFT JOIN sell_bill ON sell_bill.product_id = product.id
WHERE product.cost > sell_bill.price
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
SELECT sum (cost)-sum (price) as difference
FROM PRODUCT 
LEFT JOIN sell_bill ON sell_bill.PRODUCT_ID=PRODUCT.ID
WHERE product.cost > sell_bill.PRICE
```